# Why does Google Chrome not honor the caching headers?

Tags: google-chrome, http, caching, max-age

This is the header that I send back to my users. It's taken from the Chrome DevTools:

[image]

When I close the DevTools and refresh the page, I still get requests for this image in my servers.

[Here](https://serverfault.com/a/755660/113612) it's claimed that Google does not honor cache when we refresh the page.

I tried to open the page from a new tab, and the cache worked. Yet when I click the refresh button, Chrome does not honor the cache headers.

My question is, why does Google Chrome act like that? I mean one expects cache headers to be a universal standard to be complied by major browsers. How can I make sure my content would be cahced for performance reasons if Google Chrome disobeys HTTP standard?

Answer (score 1):

Because a lot of website has implemented caching incorrectly, and caching headers can not always be relied on. A compromise is to re-download the page if a user does a **hard refresh** of the page, and what exactly defines that? Well, for some browsers it used to be pressing `F5` or `Ctrl+R`, but simply pressing *refresh* multiple times might also be enough, because you can not expect users to know about a secret shortcut for a *hard refresh* – either way, it does not matter much to performance, because users typically do not press **refresh** unless they actually intend to **refresh the page**.

Of course, another way is if you check the checkbox that says **disable cache** in *developer tools*, causing Chrome to redownload everything, including linked resources; If you remove the checkmark it will instead say the resources were loaded from `(memory cache)` when refreshing, meaning they was loaded from the browsers cache in accordance with the cache policy of the resource.

**Note.** Chrome still shows cached requests in the **Network tab**, but it will show as loaded from `(memory cache)`.

TLS certificate errors can also cause the page not to be cached properly. E.g. If your certificate is self-signed.

Additionally, I can not reproduce the behaviour you mention; that is, only the `.html` page itself is refreshed when clicking the **refresh** button – not the linked resources such as: *images*, *video*, *JavaScript*, or *CSS* – but it could be a bug specific to your version of Chrome. When I press refresh, even multiple times, resources are still loaded from the browser cache in accordance with my websites cache policy. I verified this by monitoring my server log live while refreshing the page. E.g:

```
watch tail /var/log/xxx/sitename-access.log
```